# Hot to get a average value on analytic function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to get the average value on this BAL column for each account

```
with cte as (
select distinct t.DATE_ID,
        ad.ACCOUNT_ID
        from TIMEDATE t 
         ,  ACCOUNT_DLY ad)
         
select  cte.date_id,
        cte.Account_ID, 
        NVL(current_bal,lag (ad.current_bal) ignore nulls over (PARTITION by cte.account_id order by cte.date_id )) as bal
from cte left join ACCOUNT_DLY ad
on cte.date_id = ad.SRC_EXTRACT_DT
and cte.ACCOUNT_ID = ad.ACCOUNT_ID
order by 2,1;
```

I guess I need to use analytic function SUM or AVG again with partition on the NVL

on the top of the picture is my table on the bottom is how it suppose to look like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Dql.png

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; an explanation of the problem you are trying to solve (in plain English); and the expected output for that sample data. Do not include images; use text (preferably as DDL statements we can execute and formatted tables for the expected output).

Comment: Your picture shows a group by on time_mnth and account_id. So, just do that - GROUP BY TO_CHAR(date_id,'YYYYMM'),account_id and request the SUM in the select clause. I don't see any reason for the CTE or LAG functions you have above.

Answer (score 0):

**Analytic vs Aggregate Function**
You probably should use aggregate function AVG() ... GROUP BY instead of analytic function AVG() OVER(). The difference is that aggregate function returns one and only one row per columns it is grouped by. Analytic function puts the result in every resulting row and, in the sample as yours, that means use of DISTINCT keyword to eliminate duplicate rows which could be performance costly with bigger datasets. You can have the same result using aggregate or analytic function, though.
This is just to compare one and another - if your data is like this:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS 
        (
            Select 1 "ID", To_Date('01-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 6 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", To_Date('02-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 7 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", To_Date('03-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 8 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", To_Date('01-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 9 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", To_Date('02-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 9 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", To_Date('03-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 9 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", To_Date('01-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 6 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", To_Date('02-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 3 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", To_Date('03-JAN-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 6 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 1 "ID", To_Date('01-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 4 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", To_Date('02-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 3 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", To_Date('03-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 2 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", To_Date('01-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 6 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", To_Date('02-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 6 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", To_Date('03-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 6 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", To_Date('01-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 6 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", To_Date('02-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 9 "A_VALUE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", To_Date('03-FEB-2023', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "A_DATE", 6 "A_VALUE" From Dual
        )
```

... then use of aggregate function gives you the result you wanted...

```sql
-- Aggregate Function AVG() ... GROUP BY
Select DISTINCT 
    ID, To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyymm') "MTH", AVG(A_VALUE) "AVG_VALUE"
From 
    tbl
Group By
    ID, To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyymm')
Order By 
    To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyymm'), ID
/*
        ID MTH     AVG_VALUE
---------- ------ ----------
         1 202301          7 
         2 202301          9 
         3 202301          5 
         1 202302          3 
         2 202302          6 
         3 202302          7
*/
```

... on the other hand, using analytic function (without DISTINCT keyword) will result with the same AVG value in all rows with same ID and MONTH...

```sql
-- Analytic Function AVG() OVER()
Select --DISTINCT 
    ID, To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyymm') "MTH", AVG(A_VALUE) OVER(Partition By ID, To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyymm') ) "AVG_VALUE"
From 
    tbl
Order By 
    To_Char(A_DATE, 'yyyymm'), ID
/*
        ID MTH     AVG_VALUE
---------- ------ ----------
         1 202301          7 
         1 202301          7 
         1 202301          7 
         2 202301          9 
         2 202301          9 
         2 202301          9 
         3 202301          5 
         3 202301          5 
         3 202301          5 
         1 202302          3 
         1 202302          3 
         1 202302          3 
         2 202302          6 
         2 202302          6 
         2 202302          6 
         3 202302          7 
         3 202302          7 
         3 202302          7
```

... and if you put the DISTINCT keyword in your Select statement you will get the same result as with aggregate function above

```sql
--  using DISTINCT 
/*
        ID MTH     AVG_VALUE
---------- ------ ----------
         1 202301          7 
         2 202301          9 
         3 202301          5 
         1 202302          3 
         2 202302          6 
         3 202302          7
*/
```